# Excel CSV cell intepretation

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
"Foo","Bar","16/5"
```

Open it with Excel and it decides the the `"16/5"` is a date and displays 16 May, but I just want it to display the string verbatim on loading the CSV without having to perform any additional actions in Excel and I'm not sure how to achieve this unless I put some white space at the start of the string but that's nasty.

Comment: If you use the text import wizard you can assign the column as Text.

Comment: @TimWilliams You should post this as an answer. However, it probably belongs on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Use the Text Import Wizard - you can assign specific data types to each column as needed.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tim, that would work, but in this case the CSV is a download that users will open so I'm looking for a solution I can implement in the CSV file itself.  Turns out that some whitespace is acceptable, still nasty though.